# Comparing dicts of lists that have other dicts

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

Sorry for the confusion the title can make.

I have some dicts made out of lists of dicts, see example below:

`{spain: [{'gold':3}, {'silver':2}, {'bronze':0}], china:[{'gold':3}, {'silver':2}, {'bronze':0}]}`

I obtained the country with most medals by using:

`dict([max(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0]['gold'])])`

But now I need to know how to find if there are 2 countries with the same amount of gold medals.

I'd need to know if it returns True or False

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question? Do you want to return True/False if there are 2 countries with the same amount of medals in total?

Comment: Ok, edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: @RulerOfJustice yeah, I'd want to know if it's True/False if there are 2 countries with the same amount of gold medals in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is make a list of all the gold medals like this:

```
gmedals = [k[0]['gold'] for k in d.values()]
```

And check if the length of gmedals is the same as the set of gmedals.
Because set removes duplicates, if the lengths are the same it means there are no two countries with the same amount of gold medals. Otherwise we return True.

```
len(gmedals) != len(set(gmedals)) # True for your example
```